# How to sort a list that contains numbers and special characters alphabetically?

Tags: java, sorting, collections, io

My question is actually twofold, but first, I'm attempting to write a program which sorts a list alphabetically and write it to a file, but when attempting to sort the file, the moment that lines with special characters or numbers are introduced, the sorting no longer works. If the list is just strings that begin with letters, it sorts and write perfectly fine, and in order.

I'm simply using `Collections.sort` on a list of strings which consists of lines from an input file, and then I am attempting to write them to an output file.

My input file contains these lines:

```
These are some test lines
short line
abcdefghij
this line is much longer than the short line
123 456
#Ignore this line
Blah blah blah
# ignore this, too
```

and my output file ends up being sorted to:

```
# ignore this, too
#Ignore this line
123 456
Blah blah blah
These are some test lines
abcdefghij
short line
this line is much longer than the short line
```

As for the second question, I would like to somehow exclude the lines that being with # from being written to the file.
Here is the code I have:

```
BufferedReader inputStream = null;
        PrintWriter outputStream = null;
        String inFile = args[0];
        String outFile = args[1];
        List<String> lines = new LinkedList<>();

        try {
            inputStream =
                    new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inFile));
            outputStream=
                    new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(outFile));
            String line;
            while ((line = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
                lines.add(line);
                if(args[2].equals("LONGESTFIRST") ) {
                    Collections.sort(lines, new Comparator<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                            return o2.length() - o1.length();
                        }
                    });
                } else if (args[2].equals("SHORTESTFIRST")) {
                    Collections.sort(lines, new Comparator<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                            return o1.length() - o2.length();
                        }
                    });
                } else if (args[2].equals("LEXICOGRAPHIC")) {
                    Collections.sort(lines);
                } else if (args[2].equals("REVERSE")) {
                    Collections.sort(lines, Collections.reverseOrder());
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
                outputStream.println(lines.get(i));
            }
```

I've tried things like including the second to last line in an if statement like `if(!lines.startsWith("#") {`... but that doesn't work unfortunately.

Sorry for the wall of text by the way!

Comment: Regarding your first question: your list **is** sorted. If you want another way to sort, then precisely tell what it should be. Regarding the second one: Just don't add the line to the list, or to the output, if it starts with #. `lines.startsWith("#")` can't possibly work since `lines`is not **a** line, but the whole list of lines. `line`, or  `lines.get(i)`, is a line.

Comment: you are already implementing the ```compare``` method. Should not be that complicated to change the implementation to have it in the order you want...

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for the response! You've definitely addressed the second question. As for the first, how is it sorted alphabetically? If this was the case, "abcdefghij" would be before "blah blah blah". My understanding of the sorting is that it will by default sort alphabetically.

Comment: The natural order of STring is not the alphabetic order. It's the lexicographic order. All lowercase letters come before the uppercase letter in the lexicographic order (which is just the order of characters, based on theur numeric unicode value). You need case-insensitive ordering (see the constants defined in the String class), or a Collator (which will also deal with accented letters, and other locale-specific rules).

Comment: @JBNizet Oh okay great! I just totally misunderstood lexicographic ordering, and thought it was the same as alphabetic, thanks for clearing that up. All is well then!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is: you do not have to sort the list after **each insert** into the list.

The second one is: if you do not want lines with `#` characters present in the output, you can just check it with `list.get(i).contains("#")`. And if it returns `true`, remove this line from the list.

So the final algorithm would probably look something like:

1. Read lines from the file, add each line to the list.
2. Sort the list using one of your Comparators (**just once**), same way as you currently do.
3. Loop through the list. Check if a line is valid for writing into the file (`list.get(i).contains("#")` or anything you like), and if it is, write it to the file.

**UPDATE:**
For case-insensitive sorting you probably want to use the default comparator `CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` provided by `String` class:

```
List<String> myList = ...;
Collections.sort(myList, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just don't have to put such lines lo List

```
while ((line = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
  if (line.startsWith("#"))
    continue;
  lines.add(line);
  // ...
}
```